# amp form display different content based the server response

Tags: amp-html

I know I can use submit-success and submit-error. But I need more options.

For example, if the server returns `{"result": "0"}`, I'd like to display a message if `result=0`, show an image if `result=1`, another form if `result=2`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a custom validation that will get the server response. AFAIK, [custom-made verification](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/#form-custom-validation) reporting practice, valid values are one of: `show-first-on-submit`, `show-all-on-submit` or `else as-you-go`. You can check those custom validation if it will fit your use-case. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this will confuse with the form verification as I need to submit the form and save to the server, while verification shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [mustache sections](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Sections). The idea is to encode the different result types in the JSON response, for example:

```
{
  "message": {
    "text": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

or for an image:

```
{
  "image": {
    "src": "/my-image.png",
    "width": 300,
    "height": 200
  }
}
```

Then, you can render each result type differently in the form `submit-success` div:

```
<form ...>
  <fieldset>
    ...
  </fieldset>
  <div submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">

      {{#message}}
      <p>{{text}}</p>
      {{/message}}

      {{#image}}
      <amp-img src={{src}} layout=responsive width={{width}} height={{height}}>
       </amp-img>
      {{/image}}

    </template>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This might be a workaround, although it's testing the existence of a variable, instead of the actual value.